# How to solve TypeError: 'int' object is not subcriptable in Python?

Tags: python

I am working on a play fair cipher program where I have two functions called sameCol and sameRow, what they are suppose to do is see if two letters are in the same row or column and the code I wrote worked for a while but then broke and I do not know what I did that made it stop working properly because the program would take the key and message that needed to be encrypted and would return the encrypted message but for some reason it does not return the encrypted message.

**Update:** I tried couple more inputs for the key and message (to encrypt) and apparently some of the input's do work but some don't.

Here is an input I had done:

Enter key: lkj

Enter the message to code: fig

Result = ezez

But if I input homelike like the following then it starts showing the error again:

Enter key: run

Enter the message to encode: dik

Result:

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/../playfair.py", line 334, in <module>
  encoded = cipher.encode()
  File "/../playfair.py", line 257, in encode
  codeString = self.sameRow(row1, row2, decode = False)
  File "/../playfair.py", line 52, in sameRow
  ltr1Row = index1[0]
  TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable
```

The type error shows me the following:
`ltr1Row = index1[0]` along with the type error message, I cannot understand what is wrong with this because it was working fine and no I did not even created this variable instead my prof did.

Here is some more code of the part of `ltr1Row = index1[0]`:

```
 def sameCol(self, index1, index2, decode):
     ltr1Row = index1[0]
     ltr1Col = index1[1]
     ltr2Row = index2[0]
     ltr2Col = index2[1]
```

This is the same code for sameRow as well and I call them both later in my program as well, her is the following code for one of them:

```
    codeString = self.sameCol(col1, col2, decode = False)
```

Here is a link to the entire source code if it's needed:
https://gist.github.com/roshanlam/e0b9966af1325d5c9469f8cd3a14e402

Comment: Apparently `col1` is an `int` and not what you expect it to be.

Comment: I defined col1 as `col1 - self.getIndex(letterPair[0])`, so won't that override it or should I out it after I have declared codeString?

Comment: [mre] - this really isn't one

Comment: @DavidW I just updated my question, is it better now? I am just a freshmen in college and don't really ask questions about coding on stackoverflow so sorry about not putting the minimal reproducible example but thank you for commenting about it, I think you might have commented about this in another question of mine but I am not sure if you did then just know that I have a horrible memory and need to repeat things over and over again, so hopefully as I ask more questions I put things like minimal reproducible example in my questions

Comment: Some couple more inputs that seem to work - 1. key: adie, message to encode: rosu, result: usus           2. key: asil, message to encode: osu, result: rzrz.             3. key: ruth message to encode: osan, result: rsrs

Comment: Some inputs that don't seem to work - 1. key: nter, message to encode: ky, result: same error message as on question [!]     2.  key: ber, message to encode: rub, result: [!]

Comment: Your problem lies within the `if row1 == row2`. I dont know what this code exactly does but with the examples you gave I was able to see that everytime that code passes that check you get an exception because `sameRow()` is expecting a tuple or list and not an int.

Comment: @FrozenAra so is the following code correct: `if index1[0] == index2[0]:
                codeString = self.sameRow(index1[0], index2[0], decode = False)`

Comment: Well does it work?

Comment: Nope, it does not